# mysql IFNULL syntax i don't know what's wrong

Tags: mysql, syntax, ifnull

I'm  going to use IFNULL check in my select query

I want to execute like this, when sum is null then print 0

This is my whole query

```
SELECT 

    IFNULL(SELECT SUM(TOT_SALES_PRICE) FROM TB_DEALER_SALES_MNG WHERE DEALER_SEQ = 7 AND DATE_FORMAT(SALES_DATE, '%Y%m' )= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m') ,0) 
    )AS TOT_SALES_PRICE
```

There is a syntax error but I don't know

This is my query without IFNULL, it's working very well
advise me please

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(TOT_SALES_PRICE) FROM TB_DEALER_SALES_MNG WHERE DEALER_SEQ = 7 AND DATE_FORMAT(SALES_DATE, '%Y%m' )= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')
    )AS TOT_SALES_PRICE
```

Comment: is there (or can there be) more than one row returned from the subquery?

Comment: Could you try adding an extra set of brackets around your subquery and see if the error still occurs? `IFNULL((SELECT ....%m')),0)`

Comment: there is only one row returned

Comment: I bet @scragar is correct... put the whole subquery in parentheses.

Comment: you mean this? 
SELECT 
 
 (IFNULL(SELECT SUM(TOT_SALES_PRICE) FROM TB_DEALER_SALES_MNG WHERE DEALER_SEQ = 7 AND DATE_FORMAT(SALES_DATE, '%Y%m' )= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m') ,0) 
 )AS TOT_SALES_PRICE

Comment: this is not working..

Comment: @yevgnen No, like I said, around the subquery. `IFNULL(( SELECT SUM(COALESCE(tot_sales_price,0)) FROM tb_deaker_sales_mng WHERE dealer_seq = 7 AND DATE_FORMAT(sales_date,'%Y%m')=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m')
), 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(tot_sales_price),0)) tot_sales_price 
  FROM tb_deaker_sales_mng
 WHERE dealer_seq = 7 
   AND DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%Y%m')=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')
```

Or:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(tot_sales_price,0)) tot_sales_price 
  FROM tb_deaker_sales_mng
 WHERE dealer_seq = 7 
   AND DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%Y%m')=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')
```

Comment: This won't work if no rows are returned, which is the most likely explanation as to why he needs the `IFNULL`, I suggest putting the `COALESCE` around the `SUM`, not the other way around.

Comment: wow it's work but is it return 0 when sum is null? i don't know about COALESCE

Comment: @yevgnen, which one worked? I think if there are no rows you need one or other of the updated ones.. kindly accept the answer also :)

Comment: @yevgnen, ah ok, I have included both as the `coalesce(sum...` worked in my tests but the other one didn't.